# htmllint / HTMLlint.json?

Tags: lint

We use tslint and eslint, each of which has its own json file to govern the linting rules. I use PHPStorm and some other developers use VSCode but we use the same json file so our formatting is identical.

Is there an HTML version of this, like HTMLlint.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are but they rarely have a ton of implemented features. The best out there and easy to use is this one but there is nobody contributing to it anymore https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint

Check out their wiki https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint/wiki/